# Combining lists

Tags: haskell

I am very interested in Haskell and currently trying to solve this problem.

To solve the problem it is necessary to output List C (x,z) that matches (x,y) from List A and (y,z) from List B (without duplicates) y must be equal in A and B.

So for example:

```
A = [("z","x")]
B = [("x","c"), ("x","d")]
```

Result:

```
C = [("z","c"), ("z","d")]
```

Any ideas? I have started today with:

```
main = print(map describeList3 list_A)  

describeList3 :: ([Char], [Char]) ->Maybe [[Char]]
describeList3 element = printParam(snd element)                               

printParam :: String -> Maybe [[Char]]
printParam param = (Map.lookup param $ myFilter list_B)

myFilter :: (Ord k) => [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k [a]  
myFilter xs = Map.fromListWith (++) $ map (\(k,v) -> (k,[v])) xs
```

Currently stuck... help?

Comment: If this is homework, it's a good idea to add the tag `homework` to it.

Comment: @Arlen: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @Roger: Thanks for that! I missed that memo, and only saw it (added!) on another question elsewhere and thought it must be the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions quick and dirty solution. As for duplicates you can remove them with either nub (from Data.List), or with converting result to Data.Set and back to list.

```
nub [(x,z) | (x,y) <- a, (y',z) <- b, y == y']
```

Or with map. We create auxiliary map for list b, where value is list of values from list. And then just build for each (x,y) pair list of required (x,z) pairs (with non-nil check). Actually i think you were stuck precisely because you didn't use list comprehensions. :) Maps / filters are great for processing, but building is much easier understood in terms of list comprehensions.

```
let b' = M.fromListWith (++) [(k,[v]) | (k,v) <- b]
nub . concat $ [[(x, z) | let t = M.lookup y b', t /= Nothing, z <- fromJust t] | (x,y) <- a]
```

Comment: second part works fine as well, now I will try to put it inside main like I did before in this example codepad.org/3YwhSTF4

Comment: do you know solution for the same task/problem using SCHEME programming language ??

Comment: @Florian: Thought you were really stuck not just looking for solutions. =\ And no as for Scheme.

Comment: yeap I was really stuck, trying to figure out over all weekends, but thanks to Your post - now I understand this and the task is completed.  I just asked about Scheme because this is next what I need to do.